# Why do a density plot and a rug plot seem to disagree?

Tags: r, data-visualization, density-function

The second peak of the `density plot` is large in this example.  Why does the rug representation of the data--which seems to show few high values--not appear to match the much higher density estimated there?

How can one make rug plots less misleading?

[image]

Here's its `R` code:

```
plot(density(Boston$tax))
rug(Boston$tax, col=2, lwd=3.5)
```

Comment: You are using subjective terms like "so high" and "inadequate"...why is the second peak "too high" and why is the rug function not acceptable? What is it doing that you don't like.

Comment: This question appears to be relying on unjustified premises (at least in general). Are these questions someone else has set for you to do?

Comment: How many data points are above the level of 600?

Comment: The "problem" with the rug plot is just that one tick and several ticks in the same place look the same. You could use a spike for each distinct value whose length was proportional to number of values, i.e. a histogram with bins the distinct values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the R package `MASS`, of the $506$ total observations in `Boston`, $369$ have a value for tax below `470` and $137$ have a value for tax above `665`.  In fact `666` is by far the most common value in the data set, appearing $132$ times.

So if the area of the density plot to the left is about twice the area to the right, then that could reasonably be taken as representing the distribution.  Visual inspection suggests this might be what is happening.

A more accurate representation would have the right peak much higher and narrower, and this could be achieved by adjusting the parameters.

***Added for comments:***

For example with a much narrower bandwidth for the density function and some manual jitter:

```
library(MASS)
plot(density(Boston$tax, bw=5)) 
rug(Boston$tax + rnorm(length(Boston$tax), sd=5), col=2, lwd=3.5)
```

you would get something like this

[image: Bostontaxdensity]

Comment: You have hit upon the reason for the discrepancy.  But upon adjusting the parameters of the density estimate, the *area* of the right peak should not change and so there will still be a strong visual discrepancy between what the rug plot displays and the density plot displays. Effective solutions will--as the O.P. suggests and as @Nick Cox hints in a comment--modify the rug plot rather than the density plot.

Comment: Yeah, I used jitter for modifying the rug.

Comment: @MonaJalal could you post what the chart looks like after you made your changes? I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @RickHenderson: I added a chart with a narrower bandwidth and manual jitter

Comment: Jitter on a rug plot defeats the very purpose of indicating that **these values** are the distinct values that occur in the sample. NB distinct, not unique, which is the pivot of the question.

Answer (score 16):

The way to make a rug plot less misleading is often to use something different instead. Rug plots necessarily are relatively good at showing distinct values and very poor at indicating their relative frequency.

Here is a spike representation of the frequency distribution of the data used in the original post. The principle is that often used to show discrete distributions, a spike proportional in height to the frequency of each distinct value. The Boston data as available and documented [here](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston) were read into Stata and the `spikeplot` command used. Something similar should be trivial in all good statistical software. If you like, this is a hybrid of a histogram and a rug plot, although historically graphs of this kind may long predate rug plots.

[image]

Stata documentation for `spikeplot`, including, more to the point of this question, further examples of such graphs, is accessible [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rspikeplot.pdf)

EDIT 3 August 2022 See also [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211045583) for examples of marginal spike histograms as inspired by Harrell, F.E. 2001/2015. *Regression Modeling Strategies*. Springer.

The Boston housing data are often used as an example. Many researchers follow in the path of the original authors, who did not show any plots of the raw data in their paper. Here are four of the more unusual distributions for predictors in that dataset, as shown by quantile plots, plots of the ordered values versus an estimate of cumulative probability. The vertical axis labels are minimum, lower quartile, median, upper quartile and maximum, which in some instances coincide. A quantile plot is good for showing marked spikes and gaps in the data. Naturally an unusual (e.g. spiky) distribution doesn't stop a variable being useful as a predictor, as exemplified also by indicator or dummy variables, but it is a good idea to look at your data before modelling.
In some problems, there may be real doubts about data quality, or at least puzzles about definitions and measurements that need to inform the interpretation.

[image]