# Clear pattern in the residual vs fitted values plot

Tags: interpretation, residuals, model

I got this residuals vs fitted values plot.

[image]

As you can see there are some clear patterns of linearity. My guess is that the response depend on another variable that acts as a parameter to obtain theses lines, ie: the response should be better described as something of the form:

$$ Y = \alpha Z \cdot g(X) + e $$

for a $Z$ fixed one would obtain one of the lines we see in the plot. 
What would you think ?

Edit: Sample of the dataset.

```
>Boston[1:25,]
      crim   zn indus chas   nox    rm   age    dis rad tax ptratio  black
1  0.00632 18.0  2.31    0 0.538 6.575  65.2 4.0900   1 296    15.3 396.90
2  0.02731  0.0  7.07    0 0.469 6.421  78.9 4.9671   2 242    17.8 396.90
3  0.02729  0.0  7.07    0 0.469 7.185  61.1 4.9671   2 242    17.8 392.83
4  0.03237  0.0  2.18    0 0.458 6.998  45.8 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.63
5  0.06905  0.0  2.18    0 0.458 7.147  54.2 6.0622   3 222    18.7 396.90
6  0.02985  0.0  2.18    0 0.458 6.430  58.7 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.12
7  0.08829 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 6.012  66.6 5.5605   5 311    15.2 395.60
8  0.14455 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 6.172  96.1 5.9505   5 311    15.2 396.90
9  0.21124 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 5.631 100.0 6.0821   5 311    15.2 386.63
10 0.17004 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 6.004  85.9 6.5921   5 311    15.2 386.71
11 0.22489 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 6.377  94.3 6.3467   5 311    15.2 392.52
12 0.11747 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 6.009  82.9 6.2267   5 311    15.2 396.90
13 0.09378 12.5  7.87    0 0.524 5.889  39.0 5.4509   5 311    15.2 390.50
14 0.62976  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.949  61.8 4.7075   4 307    21.0 396.90
15 0.63796  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 6.096  84.5 4.4619   4 307    21.0 380.02
16 0.62739  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.834  56.5 4.4986   4 307    21.0 395.62
17 1.05393  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.935  29.3 4.4986   4 307    21.0 386.85
18 0.78420  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.990  81.7 4.2579   4 307    21.0 386.75
19 0.80271  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.456  36.6 3.7965   4 307    21.0 288.99
20 0.72580  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.727  69.5 3.7965   4 307    21.0 390.95
21 1.25179  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.570  98.1 3.7979   4 307    21.0 376.57
22 0.85204  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.965  89.2 4.0123   4 307    21.0 392.53
23 1.23247  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 6.142  91.7 3.9769   4 307    21.0 396.90
24 0.98843  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.813 100.0 4.0952   4 307    21.0 394.54
25 0.75026  0.0  8.14    0 0.538 5.924  94.1 4.3996   4 307    21.0 394.33
```

Comment: What are your response data? Are they *counts*, or otherwise discrete (ie, can only be 0, 1, 2, etc)?

Comment: The reponse is a continuous data. They're measures of nitrogen oxide in the air.

Comment: Are they rounded to integers or other discrete values? Can you post a small example dataset?

Comment: I gather `nox` is the response. Notice that in this sample, it is always `.538` (13x), `.469` (2x), `.458` (3x), or `.524` (7x). The many identical values is the cause of the pattern you see in the residual plot.

Comment: This appears here often. I'll try to find a duplicate. Consider the definition that residual $=$ observed $-$ fitted. So for each distinct value observed for the response, residuals fall on a line with slope $-1$. In short, parallel lines reflect granularity in the response. No need to invoke anything else.

Comment: it seems likely that the data were originally in different measurement units. Either way, a spikeplot could be informative.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188529/what-causes-bands-stripes-in-residual-plots  has a good title but the example is more exotic.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86297/why-do-a-density-plot-and-a-rug-plot-seem-to-disagree/86369#86369 explains what I mean by a spikeplot.